# The purpose of "new double"

Tags: arrays, double

```
public class JAVA_Guevarra {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //These are the variables
    double empBasicPay[] = {4000,5000,12000,6000,7500};
    double empHousingAllow[] = new double[5];
    int i;

    //This program computes for the payment of the employees
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        empHousingAllow[i] = 0.2 * empBasicPay[i];
        //This loop statement gets 20% of the employee basic payment
    }
    System.out.println("Employee Basic and House Rental Allowance");

    for(i = 0; i<5; i++){
        System.out.println(empBasicPay[i] + " " + empHousingAllow[i]);
        //This prints out the final output of the first loop statement
    }
}


}
```

What does the `new double[5]` do in this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not just `new double`, it is `new double[5]` which create an array for maximum 5 doubles

as oracle doc explain it well (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

```
// declares an array of integers
int[] anArray;

// allocates memory for 10 integers
anArray = new int[10];

// initialize first element
anArray[0] = 100;
// initialize second element
anArray[1] = 200;
```

so `double empHousingAllow[] = new double[5];` allocate memory for an array of five doubles

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword in Java is used to create objects. In this case, the object which is being created is an array containing five doubles.

You might want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java), which describes declaration of arrays in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the concept required size when you define an array, later you can not change the size.

You can not assign value directly to the memory block like

```
double d[5];
d[0] = 10.05;
```

you need to create memory block with specific type.
That's why you need to define an array in that manner.

```
double d[] = new double[5]
```

Or

```
double d[5];
d[0] = new double like that.
```

then you can add the value to that block.